# MySQL Workbench system variables discrepancy

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-workbench, utf8mb4

MySQL Workbench: v8.0.13
MySQL: v5.7 (installed by brew on macOS 10.14.13)

Server variables tab, everything looks as expected, the options file (my.cnf) has the same settings.
[image]

Actually this is how it behaves. eg. character_set_results switches back to utf8 instead of utf8mb4.
[image]

Why are the two views different? What causes the difference?

Comment: What do you see if you use `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` (it defaults to `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-new.html says:

> When opening connections, MySQL Workbench automatically sets the client character set to utf8.

You can execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` after you open a connection in MySQL Workbench.

This has been the subject of a bug report against MySQL Workbench:

[Bug #78503: MySQL WorkBench's Encoding is Hardcoded to UTF-8](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78503)

I suggest you go log into that page and click the "Affects Me" button to register your interest.